# Error: Invalid operands to binary expression double double, but I'm not using pointers, only using ints

Tags: c

From here and google, I thought the "invalid operands to binary expression double and double" error meant I was trying to operate on doubles or floats when that's not allowed (for some reason) or that I'm messing around with pointers (which I haven't figured out quite yet). Yet I got everything going on here in ints (I think) and I'm not using pointers (that I"m aware of).

I'm just trying to play around with charting out different equations, I'm not really sure what's going on. I wanted to use floats so I could see decimals but I reduced everything down to ints in a desperate attempt to get what I thought would be a simple program to run.

What am I missing here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int pricedecrease(int x)
{
    return x - ((0.1 * x) ^ 3);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d", pricedecrease(100));
}
```

Comment: What is `^ 3` supposed to do?  `^` is exclusive-or in C.

Comment: It's suppose to raise to the power of 3... right?

Comment: `^` is bitwise operator in C.  See @FatalError's answer for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing is *type promotion*. `0.1` is a `double`, so `0.1 * x` is also a `double`.

You could cast the result like:

```
return x - ((int)(0.1 * x) ^ 3);
```

or simply avoid using a `double` altogether:

```
return x - ((x / 10) ^ 3);
```

Comment: Ok cool, thank you, I got that working. But what if I want the result in a double, how do I get that?

Comment: I think Fiddling Bits' comment is right on.  I didn't catch it at first glance, but if you wanted to take something to the 3rd power, you want `pow()`, i.e. `pow(0.1 * x, 3)`

Comment: Might have some problems linking the math library, depending on how you're compiling/linking.